# How to indent second line?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to indent second line only, but the new line is creating by automatically. Anyone help?

```
string text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccc";

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
rect.Border = Rectangle.BOX;
rect.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
rect.BorderColor = BaseColor.RED;
cb.Rectangle(rect);

ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.Add(new Chunk(text, bf));
ct.AddElement(p);
ct.Go();
```

Current result:

[image: current result]

Expected result:

[image: expect result]

Comment: Seems like you want to indent all the lines except the second?

Comment: Can i control a single row ?